# Unable to show/hide button on checkbox check in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I'm using ASP.NET checkbox controls. And what I'm trying to do is to simply change visibility of button on checkbox change event.
If checkbox is checked then hide button, else if it is unchecked show the button.

I have 2 problems with my jQuery code.

1. On initial change event does not get triggered. I've putted break point on jQuery code and function doesn't get invoked. On second change it gets invoked regularly.
2. When button shows it is visible only for less then second, and then goes back to hidden, even thou it showed be visible until next change.

This is my ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="upDirectDebitPanel" runat="server" EnableViewState="True">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="divSameAsMerchant" visible="False">
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSameAsMerchantBank" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkSameAsMerchantBank_CheckedChanged" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chkSameAsMerchantBank" ID="lblSameAsMerchantBank" meta:resourcekey="lblSameAsMerchantBank"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowBankInformationModal" meta:resourcekey="btnShowBankInformationModal" CausesValidation="False" style="visibility: hidden"/>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And this is jQuery code:

```
var sameAsMerchantBank = $('#<%=chkSameAsMerchantBank.ClientID%>');
var btnShowBankInformationModal = $('#<%=btnShowBankInformationModal.ClientID%>');

$(sameAsMerchantBank).change(function () {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $(btnShowBankInformationModal).css("visibility", "hidden");
     }
     $(btnShowBankInformationModal).css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

This is backend event for that checkbox:

```
protected void chkSameAsMerchantBank_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkSameAsMerchantBank.Checked)
    {
        SetShortAccountInfo(merchantIban.Value, merchantAccountNumber.Value,
                    merchantSwiftNumber.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        SetShortAccountInfo(directDebitIban.Value, directDebitAccountNumber.Value, directDebitSwiftNumber.Value);
    }
}
```

Anybody knows what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: try by `$(document).on("change",sameAsMerchantBank,function () {
 //do stuff
 });
`

Comment: Also you should write `else` it enters every time for `$(btnShowBankInformationModal).css("visibility", "visible");`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Yes thanks, I've just noticed that about missing else part. That solved one part of problem. But still button gets showed only for short time...

Comment: yes because you are having `Checked="True"` and then this `change` event fires after `DOM` loaded

Comment: Can you please share what you have performed under `chkSameAsMerchantBank_CheckedChanged` event.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Sure, I will update my question in a second. Basically I have some textboxes that I'm filling in depending on a state of that checkbox in backend.

Comment: You are having `AutoPostBack="True"` and you are making server `call` and used Update Panel.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Yes I do. I have to cause of some other functionalities. Usually I've put return false after showing button, but I cannot avoid postback like that...

Comment: Have you change your code with `.on`? as per i suggested.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I've just realized that this is impossible, cause as you've said before for first change control is not in DOM cause of UpdatePanel and PostBack. So I will do bad practice and hide/show button from the backend.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. Have you tried with `.on()`?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I've did. The main problem is that someone, sometime in the past used devExpress control that demands using of UpdatePanel. If you ask me I would refactor all into javaScript. Cause as you can see, it causing problems.

Comment: yes you have to do all with either client side change or server side change. Do not mix both for the same control.

Comment: @nemo_87: I have added a solution for you, try it out and see if it meets your requirement. Hope! this sorts out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code do

```
//changes made here
//$(sameAsMerchantBank).change(function () {
$(document).on("change",sameAsMerchantBank,function () {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $(btnShowBankInformationModal).css("visibility", "hidden");
     }
     //always goes here
     //$(btnShowBankInformationModal).css("visibility", "visible");
     //put else
     else{
       $(btnShowBankInformationModal).css("visibility", "visible");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem before.and this is a common problem for update panels.there are 2 ways of it to solve.
Either use a trigger to that checkbox or use the code below:

```
function load() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(jsFunctions);
}
function jsFunctions() {            
        $("#btnClick").click(function () {                    
            alert("Alert: Hello from jQuery!");
    });
}
```

this code.rebind your event in jsfunctions function.

Comment: You're adding code the wrong way. Add 4 spaces before each line or select all code and click on `{ }` (the code icon) in the editor. I also edited it for you :)

Comment: Don't have to be sorry buddy, glad I could help!